# Как сделать кликабельным номер телефона, приходящий на почту

Tags: php, html, joomla

В PHP имеются строки:

```
<?php if ($this->config_fields['d_mobil_phone']['display']){?>
<tr>
   <td width="160"><?php print _JSHOP_MOBIL_PHONE?>:</td>
   <td><?php print $this->order->d_mobil_phone?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Они выводят номер телефона, введенного пользователем.
Куда вставить код "tel:" чтобы выводимый телефон стал кликабельный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

> `<td><?php print $this->order->d_mobil_phone?></td>`

вставьте ссылку

```
<?php
  printf('<td><a href="tel:%s">%1$s</a></td>', $this->order->d_mobil_phone);
?>
```

Comment: Вместо указанной строчки вставляю, но не кликабельный телефон

Comment: @sander покажите фрагмент **сгенерированной*** html странички с этим кодом

Comment: <tr>
           <td width="160">Мобильный телефон:</td>
           <td><a target="_blank" rel="noopener"><span class="js-phone-number highlight-phone" data-title="Позвонить через Веб-Агент">+7 000 000 00 00</span></a></td>        </tr>

Comment: Это я смотрю через почту мэйл. А если почтовым клиентом заходить, то телефон виден как текст

Comment: @sander мой код не мог сгенерировать такие строки. Давайте обсуждать реальный код

Comment: Может быть не работает как ссылка потому что, переменная не вся обернута как гиперссылка?

Comment: @sander пока нет реального кода и реального вывода я Вам ничем помочь не могу

Comment: <tr>
           <td width="160">Мобильный телефон:</td>
           <td><a href="tel:+75798709808" class="daria-goto-anchor" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">+75798709808</a></td>        </tr>

Comment: @sander данная ссылка вполне кликабельна

Comment: <?php echo '<a href="tel:+70000000000"> Тел: +70000000000</a>';?> причем такой вывод работает, но не могу прикрутить это: $this->order->d_mobil_phone

Comment: @sander я Вам привел код. Но Вы упорно не желаете его использовать

Comment: мне не получается прислать html код именно почтового клиента, т.к. это мобильное приложение

Comment: я использую ваш код, он работает в браузере, но в мобильном приложении нет. Хотя этот работет: <?php echo '<a href="tel:+70000000000"> Тел: +70000000000</a>';?>

Comment: Прошу прощения за настойчивость, я не разбираюсь в php и в дискуссии пытаюсь найти истину :)

Comment: Ваш ответ верный, ссылка стала кликабельной, проблема была у меня в кеше. Спасибо!

Comment: @sander так отметьте его как верный

Answer (score 2):

За кликабельность телефона отвечает HTML, который формируется вашим кодом PHP

```
    <?php if ($this->config_fields['d_mobil_phone']['display']){?>
    <tr>
       <td width="160"><?php print _JSHOP_MOBIL_PHONE?>:</td>
       <td>
          <a href="tel:<?php print $this->order->d_mobil_phone?>">
             <?php print $this->order->d_mobil_phone?>
          </a>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Полную информацию про [все способы как сделать кликабельным номер телефона](https://domhtml.ru/kak-sdelat-klikabelnyj-nomer-telefona-na-sajte/) или почту, скайп и т.д можно прочитать на сайте

Answer (score 2):

Кликабельным телефон можно сделать так:

```
<a href=”tel:+13335557799”>Звонок</a>
```

[Источник](https://domhtml.ru/kak-sdelat-klikabelnyj-nomer-telefona-na-sajte/).